# Archive validation failed. Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, validation

I'll describe a little bit the problem, I'm using Xcode 7.2 and I'm also using cocoa pods, my problem is that I get the following error while validating my archive: 
[image]

I've already checked the build settings and it's still not working. Any one has an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that for some reason Xcode fails to validate the archive if the "Include app symbols for your application..." box is checked so simply uncheck this box while validating the archive for it to work.

[image]